# How to build with IndigoOlive.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WPF

Tags: wpf, windows, xamarin.forms

I installed IndigoOlive.Xamarin.Forms.WPF and bought a license and I cannot get the thing to build.  I am just building the demo project on GitHub.

Comment: Should you perhaps be contacting their support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes he should have contacted my support.  But to answer him, I had some issues with my tutorial on GitHub.  That is corrected now and should run very smooth.

Comment: Yes, I retried the tutorial and it works fine.  using Xamarin.Forms was missing in your documentation.  I should have known that anyways.